# Sending Plain Text Emails

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to send plain text emails to a company who will be processing them for me. I am using the Swift Mailer library and as far as I can tell - I have no problems. But the company that I am sending the messages to says that they are coming into them with all of the data on a single line. When I send myself an email using this script it looks perfect - each piece of data is on a separate line.

Here is the script I am using. It is very simple.

```
<?php   
$to="";

$bcc="";

$subject = "Quote" ;

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    //Message
$message = "Domestic Quote Request\n";
$message .= "Full Name: $_POST[name]\n";
$message .= "Email: $_POST[email]\n";
$message .= "Phone: $_POST[phone]\n";
$message .= "Pickup Date: $_POST[shipdate]\n";
$message .= "Pickup City or Zip: $_POST[pickupzip]\n";
$message .= "Drop Off City or Zip: $_POST[dropoffzip]\n";
$message .= "Year: $_POST[vehicleyear]\n";
$message .= "Make: $_POST[vehiclemake]\n";
$message .= "Model: $_POST[vehiclemodel]\n";
$message .= "Carrier Type: $_POST[carriertype]\n";
$message .= "This Quote is from $domain";


require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create the message
$the_message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// Give the message a subject
->setSubject($subject)

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom($_POST['email'])

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array($to))

->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding())

// Give it a body
->setBody($message, 'text/plain', 'us-ascii');

//Check is BCC Field is emtpy. 
if ( !empty($bcc) ) 
{   //The BCC Field is not empty so set it.  
    $the_message->setBcc(explode(',', $bcc));
}

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($the_message); 
    }
    header("location:index.php?s=1");
?>
```

Here is an example of what the company is saying they are receiving:

```
Domestic Quote Request  Full Name: Test  Email: someone@somewhere.com  Phone: 555-555-5555     Pickup Date: 07/02/2012  Pickup City or Zip: 12938  Drop Off City or Zip: 23981  Year: 2009  Make: Audi  Model: A4  Carrier Type: enclosed carrier  This Quote is from awebsite.com
```

And this is what I receive when I email myself.

```
Domestic Quote Request
Full Name: Test
Email: someone@somewhere.com
Phone: 555-555-5555
Pickup Date: 07/02/2012
Pickup City or Zip: 12938
Drop Off City or Zip: 23981
Year: 2009
Make: Audi
Model: M4
Carrier Type: enclosed carrier
This Quote is from awebsite.com
```

The company said that they believed that the lead was being sent as free text instead of plain text. Is there such a thing? I have never heard of free text.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the web client they are viewing the email in parses emails in HTML. So instead of \n try `<br />` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Email body requires Microsoft \r\n line endings.
The headers require Linux \n line endings.